# Determine MP3 bit depth in Python via Mutagen

Tags: python, mp3, lame, mutagen

Is there a way to determine an MP3 file's encoded bit depth (ie 8, 16, 24, 32) in Python using the Mutagen library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transformations done by the MP3 encoding process drop completely the concept of “bit depth”. You can only know the bit depth of the *source* audio if such information was stored in a tag of the MP3 file. Otherwise, you can take the MP3 data and produce 8-bit, 16-bit or 24-bit audio.

Answer (score 0):

I've not heard "bit depth" with regard to mp3s so I'm assuming you mean bit *rate*.  From the [Mutagen tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/wiki/Tutorial):

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
audio = MP3("example.mp3")
print audio.info.length, audio.info.bitrate
```

That second portion (`audio.info.bitrate`) should be what you need.

Comment: Yeah, I've definitely been able to discover MP3 bitrates using Mutagen, it's pretty easy like you demonstrated :) I would, however, like to know if the audio is 8bit, 16bit, or 24bit. I've been able to get sample rate, bit rate, but I can't seem to find a way to get bit depth.